# How to combine various distance functions into one given the following dataset?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a few distance functions which return distance between two images , I want to combine these distance into a single distance, using weighted scoring e.g. `ax1+bx2+cx3+dx4` etc  i want to learn these weights automatically such that my test error is minimised.

For this purpose i have a labeled dataset which has various triplets of images such that (a,b,c) , *a* has less distance to *b* than it has to *c*. 
i.e. `d(a,b)<d(a,c)`

I want to learn such weights so that this ordering of triplets can be as accurate as possible.(i.e. the weighted linear score given is less for a&b and more for a&c).

What sort of machine learning algorithm can be used for the task,and how the desired task can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly, but it seems that this could be solved more easily with constrained optimization directly, rather than classical machine learning (the algorithms of which are often implemented via constrained optimization, see e.g. SVMs).

As an example, a possible objective function could be:

```
argmin_{w} || e ||_2 + lambda || w ||_2
```

where `w` is your weight vector (Oh god why is there no latex here), `e` is the vector of errors (one component per training triplet), `lambda` is some tunable regularizer constant (could be zero), and your constraints could be:

```
max{d(I_p,I_r)-d(I_p,I_q),0} <= e_j for jth (p,q,r) in T s.t. d(I_p,I_r) <= d(I_p,I_q)
```

for the `j`th constraint, where `I_i` is image `i`, `T` is the training set, and

```
d(u,v) = sum_{w_i in w} w_i * d_i(u,v)
```

with `d_i` being your `i`th distance function.

Notice that `e` is measuring how far your chosen weights are from satisfying all the chosen triplets in the training set. If the weights preserve ordering of label `j`, then `d(I_p,I_r)-d(I_p,I_q) < 0` and so `e_j = 0`. If they don't, then `e_j` will measure the amount of violation of training label `j`. Solving the optimization problem would give the best `w`; i.e. the one with the lowest error.

If you're not familiar with linear/quadratic programming, convex optimization, etc... then start googling :) Many libraries exist for this type of thing.

On the other hand, if you would prefer a machine learning approach, you may be able to adapt some [metric learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning#Metric_learning) approaches to your problem.